# npm install -g composer-cli@0.20 failed

Tags: hyperledger-composer

npm install -g composer-cli@0.20 failed with bellow error

../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_args.h:22:10: fatal error: 'grpc/compression.h' file not found

## include

```
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

1 error generated.░⸩ ⠇ install: info lifecycle grpc@1.10.1~install: Failed to exec install script
make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/connected_channel.o] Error 1

Comment: What version of node are you using?  Composer supports version Node version 8.

Answer (score 2):

Running these 2 prerequisite commands before the composer installation has fixed the issue for me: (as listed on 
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html)

nvm install v8

nvm use 8